# OSGI @Reference never assigned in Intelij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, osgi

InelliJ IDEA (2022.2.3) show @References as never assigned. In runtime, correct bean is injected. Is it possible to show Intellij this class to remove false-positive warning about not never assigned field?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: IDEA doesn't know much (without plugins) about OSGi/SCR (at least that's how I interpret this annotation). You can always hit alt-enter and chose to ignore such kind of warning.